# Using constructor after Stream consumption

Tags: java, java-stream

Let's say I have a Class MyClass with this constructor

```
public MyClass(double[] column){
   //...
}
```

Would it be possible to write something like

```
MyClass myClass=IntStream
    .range(0, column.length)
    .mapToDouble(i->modify(column[i]))
    .instantiateFromArray(MyClass::new);
```

instead of

```
MyClass myClass=new MyClass(
    IntStream.range(0, column.length).mapToDouble(i->modify(column[i])).toArray()
  );
```

Comment: The only way to do something like that would be writing your own Collector and it's not worth the trouble. Basically the problem is that the Streams don't know how many elements there is in a stream - it's dynamic, so basically you would need to get the array from the MyClass - create new one with the same values but size + 1 and put the new values at the end - and so on and so on.

Comment: @sycyhy even then there is no Collector for primitive streams. This would be possible with an instantiate extension function in Kotlin

Comment: @jb-nizet boxed() to the rescue !:) - jokes aside thanks :) totally forgot about that :)

Comment: Ok, I guess the simplest option would be for me to create a live template, as I am using intellij. Just have to learn how to.

Comment: Can you change the constructor of `MyClass` to accept a `List<Double>` instead of `double[]`?

Comment: If so, would there be a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your constructor stays as is: `public MyClass(double[] column)`, I'm afraid you can't do better than you're doing.

On the other hand, if you could change your constructor to:

```
public MyClass(List<Double> column)
```

Then you could do as follows:

```
MyClass myClass = IntStream.range(0, column.length)
    .mapToObj(i -> modify(column[i]))
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toList(),
        MyClass::new));
```

This uses [`Collectors.collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-), which accepts a collector and then uses the result as the input of the given function. In this case, we first collect the `Double` values to a `List` and then use a reference to the constructor of `MyClass` as the function (the constructor can be seen as a function that receives a `List<Double>` as an argument and returns an instance of `MyClass`).

Disclaimer: I wouldn't do all these changes just for the sake of code style. Arrays are faster and can hold primitive values, while a `List` can only hold objects. I'd only go for this option if there's a gain in having a list instead of an array within the `MyClass` class.